# Island Perimeter - Failing to count all neighbors in a grid

Tags: python, backtracking

I am trying to solve a leetcode problem given by the example below. 
Example:

```
[[0,1,0,0],  
 [1,1,1,0],  
 [0,1,0,0],  
 [1,1,0,0]]
```

Answer: 16
Explanation: The perimeter is the 16 yellow stripes in the image below:
[image]

My method is to find a cell that is a part of the island and traverse through its neighboring cells. Sometimes I fail to count all the neighbors. I believe is due to one of these two things:
- erasing cells when I visit them
- solving this problem recursively
Logically it makes sense to erase a cell and traverse through its surrounding neighbors recursively, but I do fail the occasional test case like the following.

```
[[1,1,1,1],  
 [1,0,0,1],  
 [1,0,0,1],  
 [1,1,1,1]]
```

I return 26 instead of 24.

I am sure it is because of the way the cells are connected. I am just having trouble figuring out why the logic does not make sense. In theory, the answer should be the **number of islands *4 - the number of neighbors * 2** but my algorithm fails to count one neighbor. In problems like

```
[[0,0,0,0],  
 [1,1,1,1],  
 [1,1,1,1],  
 [1,1,1,1]]
```

I return 26 instead of 14! Again, I am missing neighbors

```
class Solution(object):
    def islandPerimeter(self, grid):
        """
        :type grid: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: int
        """
        p = {}
        p[0]=0

        def perimeter(i, j):
            if (grid[i][j]):
                p[0]=p[0]+4
                grid[i][j]=0
            if(i-1>-1):
                if (grid[i-1][j]):
                    p[0]=p[0]-2
                    perimeter(i-1,j)
            if(j-1>-1):
                if (grid[i][j-1]):
                    p[0]=p[0]-2
                    perimeter(i,j-1)
            if(j+1<len(grid[0])):
                if (grid[i][j+1]):
                    p[0]=p[0]-2
                    perimeter(i,j+1)
            if (i+1<len(grid)):
                if (grid[i+1][j]):
                    p[0]=p[0]-2
                    perimeter(i+1,j)

        for i in range (0, len(grid)):
            for j in range (0,len(grid[0])):
                if (grid[i][j]):
                    perimeter(i,j)
                    return p[0]

        return 0
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please [mark it as 'accepted’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the grid and the yellow perimeter, I immediately see the line segments as edges of a graph, where vertices are the (x,y) coordinates of the grid.

So, my take at solving this problem is to represent the occupied squares with 4 edges in the (undirected) graph.

If you scan the occupied cells top to bottom, left to right, all you have to do is to toggle the 4 edges of each cell (i.e. create an edge if it does not exist, or remove the edge if it exists).

This solution is easy to describe in words, and easy to translate to code, and the resulting code looks easy to read (in my opinion, but that's subjective).

```
def to_graph(map):
    g={}
    def toggle_edge(e1, e2):
        e = tuple(sorted((e1, e2)))
        if e in g: del g[e]
        else: g[e] = 1
    for i, row in enumerate(map):
        for j, val in enumerate(row):
            if val:
                toggle_edge((i,j), (i,j+1))
                toggle_edge((i,j+1), (i+1,j+1))
                toggle_edge((i+1,j+1), (i+1,j))
                toggle_edge((i+1,j), (i,j))
    return g
```

To get the value of the solution we just count the number of edges in the graph.

```
print(sum(to_graph([[0,1,0,0],
                    [1,1,1,0],
                    [0,1,0,0],
                    [1,1,0,0]]).values()))
# 16
print(sum(to_graph([[1,1,1,1],
                    [1,0,0,1],
                    [1,0,0,1],
                    [1,1,1,1]]).values()))
# 24
print(sum(to_graph([[0,0,0,0],
                    [1,1,1,1],
                    [1,1,1,1],
                    [1,1,1,1]]).values()))
# 14
```

I'm sorry I didn't go through your code, as that's not easy to follow without some comments.